# How to use rails post method to get data from client side(android)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, post, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to use post method for getting data alone from client side,How to use post method in def create function for getting data alone.

post controller.rb

```
def create 

    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Prayer Successfully created."
      @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5)
    else 
      flash[:notice] = "Error"
      @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5)
    end


  end
```

Post method for getting data from client side,i have to use def create,i am new to ruby on rails,i dont know to use that data from client side using the post method.

Comment: @rony36,coould you tell your gtalk id,i am not getting the solution,

Answer (score 1):

should try this for `JSON` or `XML`

```
def create 
 respond_to do |format|

   @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Prayer Successfully created."
      @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5)
      format.xml { render :xml => @post, :status => :created }
      format.json{ render :json => @post, :status => :created }
    else 
      flash[:notice] = "Error"
      @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5)
      format.xml { render :xml => @post, :status => :created }
      format.json{ render :json => @post, :status => :created }
    end
 end 
end
```

**Updated**

**fetch data (from client end) and create**

create an `action` in your `controller`

```
def create_from_app
   data_json = JSON.parse request.body.read

   @post = Post.new(data_json)
   @post.save
end
```

your android application will hit this action (url something like http://www.exaple.com/create_from_app) with data. This action gonna parse these data and create a post as your expectation.

Comment: ya dude,i want to use json only,bcz for parsing data i used json only.From my client side,they will send an data or text,how it will fetches using this code@rony

Comment: http://floating-wildwood-1154.herokuapp.com/  this is my ror site,in this side i am parsing json data which has the content only in my android apps,right now if i add some thing in android it has to show the content,vice versa,for that i want to use post method]

Comment: I'm little bit confused about your question. you can prepare `@post` object as json format in this way. Are you asking for "how to parse json data?". If so,`parsed_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(your_json_string_or_your_requested_object)`

Comment: if i am sending data from client side,it has to fetch data using post method in def create funciton

Comment: I dont want to send data or text from website,i want to get data from client side and wants to display in website

Comment: ,what are the things i want to add in def create function for posting data

Comment: how to create as post object using json,in def create funciton @rony36 i am just getting data only

Comment: ok, you getting data? it's great. now from different application you can create another POST request with these data, right? like `Post.new.from_json(your_json_data)`

Comment: dude in my def create function,what are the thing i want to add,for getting data from client side,if i will send mydata from client side,how to get this one

Comment: format.json { render json: @post_names = {:post => @posts.as_json(:only=> :content)} } this is the line for parsing data from our website(server) to android apps(client side).  Rightnow i want to do in reverse order,if some one sends data from android,we want to fetch data and display in website

Comment: where i have to write the code,what the code looks ,can you exlain in answer

Comment: are you there @rony36, what are the changes i want to do dude,i am very confused,could you give your gtalk id

Comment: dude i have to write only updated in my controller or both the thing i want to write in my controller

Comment: http://pastebin.com/e0axwZiC   can you look at this link,here i mention my controller,what the thing i want to do there,@rony36

Comment: ,your second code is right,can you do where i have to do in my code,how to change my create function for my requirement,help me rony

Comment: ,are you there,i felt that we are nearer to answer,could you guide me to get correct solution,how to get that data dude

Comment: ,are you there,i didnt get the solution,

Comment: are you there?hello,i am not getting the solution

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30730/discussion-between-rony36-and-jitendra-patidar)